# How to avoid stringly-typed code in ASP.NET MVC Display attribute?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

When using `DataAnnotations.Display` attribute combined with localized strings, the syntax which is used is the following:

```
public class Customer
{
    [Display(ResourceType = typeof(DisplayResources), Name = "LName")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

*Source: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayattribute.name%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).*

Apparently, the following syntax is impossible:

```
public class Customer
{
    [Display(Name = DisplayResources.LName)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

since it results in the following compile error:

> An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type

What else I can do to avoid passing variables by their names through a string? Is there a way to avoid stringly-typed code?

Comment: I see someone's exercising their newly-acquired [programmer jargon vocabulary](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/07/new-programming-jargon.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is an article form ex-Telerik member Kazi Manzur Rashid. [Localization with ASP.NET MVC ModelMetadata](http://weblogs.asp.net/rashid/archive/2010/06/14/localization-with-asp-net-mvc-modelmetadata.aspx). He is explaining there how to use nice framework [MvcExtensions](http://mvcextensions.github.com) ([help articles](https://github.com/MvcExtensions/Core/wiki))

Here is an example:

```
public class ProductEditModelConfiguration : ModelMetadataConfiguration<ProductEditModel>
{
    public ProductEditModelConfiguration()
    {
        Configure(model => model.Id).Hide();

        Configure(model => model.Name).DisplayName(() => LocalizedTexts.Name)
            .Required(() => LocalizedTexts.NameCannotBeBlank)
            .MaximumLength(64, () => LocalizedTexts.NameCannotBeMoreThanSixtyFourCharacters);

        Configure(model => model.Category).DisplayName(() => LocalizedTexts.Category)
            .Required(() => LocalizedTexts.CategoryMustBeSelected)
            .AsDropDownList("categories", () => LocalizedTexts.SelectCategory);

        Configure(model => model.Price).DisplayName(() => LocalizedTexts.Price)
            .FormatAsCurrency()
            .Required(() => LocalizedTexts.PriceCannotBeBlank)
            .Range(10.00m, 1000.00m, () => LocalizedTexts.PriceMustBeBetweenTenToThousand);
    }
}
```